# How I can store multiple links in RecyclerView and than use those links in Adaptor class

Tags: android, kotlin, url, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

**how i can store different urls and each url acts differently when clicked by the user**

**This is data model class**

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.laptopguide.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.laptopguide.databinding.ActivityWindowsLaptopBinding

class WindowsLaptop : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var binding: ActivityWindowsLaptopBinding
        
        private lateinit var laptopAdapter: LaptopAdapter
        private lateinit var dataList:ArrayList<ItemsViewModel>
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityWindowsLaptopBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        dataList = ArrayList<ItemsViewModel>()
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)", "54999", "Buy Now"))
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)", "54999", "Buy Now"))
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)","54999", "Buy Now"))
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)","54999", "Buy Now"))
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)","54999", "Buy Now"))
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)","54999", "Buy Now"))
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)","54999", "Buy Now"))
        dataList.add(ItemsViewModel(R.drawable.images, "Ideapad Gaming 3", "i5 12th Generation (16 GB/512 GB SSD)", "54999", "Buy Now"))
                


        laptopAdapter = LaptopAdapter(dataList, this)
        binding.rvLaptop.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvLaptop.adapter = laptopAdapter
    }
}
```

**Like this is a laptop guide application user can see the laptop and when user decide to buy a laptop i want to redirect user to amazon via the link so every laptop have their own url so how i can store and use those urls for specific button**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.laptopguide.databinding.LaptopDesignBinding

class LaptopAdapter(var dataList:ArrayList<ItemsViewModel>, var context:Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<LaptopAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LaptopAdapter.ViewHolder {

        var binding = LaptopDesignBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LaptopAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        anima(holder.itemView)
        holder.binding.ivImage.setImageResource(dataList.get(position).laptopImage)
        holder.binding.tvName.text = dataList.get(position).laptopName
        holder.binding.tvSpecs.text = dataList.get(position).laptopSpecs
        holder.binding.tvPrice.text = dataList.get(position).laptopPrice
        holder.binding.btnBuy.text = dataList.get(position).laptopBuy
        holder.binding.btnShare.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.type = "text/plain"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Share this")
            val chooser =Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share This Laptop Using....")
            context.startActivity(chooser)
        }
        holder.binding.btnBuy.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener(){
            val intent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse("")
            context.startActivity(intent)
        })
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(var binding:LaptopDesignBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


    fun anima (view:View){

            var animation= AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f)
            animation.duration = 1500
            view.startAnimation(animation)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a url field in your ItemsViewModel class

```
data class ItemsViewModel(
    ...
    val url: String
)
```

and then in adapter you can get this url per item with just `dataList.get(position).url` like:

```
holder.binding.btnBuy.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener(){
    val intent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    intent.data = Uri.parse(dataList.get(position).url)
    context.startActivity(intent)
})
```